# How to add shaking effects in an app using UIResponder çlass

Tags: iphone

I have two question:
1)How can I add shaking effects in an iphone app using UIResponder Class.

2)I have two views Parent View & Child View where I am going to the child view from parent view,  using present modal view controller and there is an image in the child view that should is showing but the problem is that I want that in the child view the image should cover only half of the screen and user should be able to see the parent view in the back side of the image as well.

Please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

shaking effect can be added with the help of the following methods of the UIResponder class

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

if you want the user to see only half of the image then set the frame of the UIImageView or the view in which you are showing the image to half of the window. I didn't get the last part of your question can you elaborate that

Comment: Hi Radix,Many Thanks for your help, actually I am going to navigate to the child view from the parent view and as there is an image in the child view so that will be displayed, but i want while showing the picture of the child view picture should cover only some part of screen and user is able to see the parent view in the back, for that i have resized the size of image view and set the clear color for the background of the child view but still i m not able to show the parent view at the back side of the picture, i hope that i would have been able to put my requirements clearly now, thanks